# How to prove that $f$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Given  the real function $f$ defined by

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0 \ \text{if} <0 \\  x\ \text{if} \ x \ge 0 \end{cases}$

**My thinking** :I know that  $f$ is not open  as the image  of the open set $(-1,1)$ is $[0,1)$

And  $f$ is closed  as the image  of the closed set $[-1,1]$ is $[0,1]$

**My question** :  How to prove that $f$   is  closed  ?

Note :  I need theoritical proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a set $A$ is closed, then $B= A \cap [0,\infty)$ is closed. Also, the union of the two closed sets $B$ and $\{0\}$ is closed. $f(A)$ is either $B$, or $B \cup \{0\}$